# Capturing block, repeated more times

Tags: regex

Let's say I have this regex

```
((?:[^"]|\\")*="(?:[^"]|\\")*"(?:\sand)?){0,}
```

and I would like to match a string like

```
username="username" and name="name" and lastname="lastname"
```

and, of course, I would like to have all into the same capturing block.
With this regex I can obtain only `lastname="lastname"`.

Someone could explain me why?

PS.: I perfectly know that this will match also an "and" without any other "predicate" after, but I'm tackling this one step at a time

Comment: @vks so it's not possible to extract all the string I want?

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex engine only remembers the last group.You can simply use this instead

```
((?:(?:[^"]|\\")*="(?:[^"]|\\")*"(?:\sand)?){0,})
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lS1nO8/2

You can group all together instead of grouping individual parts.

Comment: This not fulfil my needs as it's only a little part of my regex and, even if this was suitable for my needs, I need only one match (I'm using behat that expects only one parameter from this parsing)

Comment: vks: yes! if you can update your answer and explain it in detail, would be great :)